# Update related record fields lightning data service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a record loaded with Lightning Data Service. I try to set related record values like so

```
var prescription = component.get("v.prescription"); //lightning data service record
console.log(prescription.Patient__c); // prints the Id of the lookup record
prescription.Patient__r.Authorize_Dot_Net_Profile_Id__c = parsed.customerProfileId;
component.set("v.prescription", prescription);
```

but I get an error on the 3rd line

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot add property Authorize_Dot_Net_Profile_Id__c, object is not extensible]

Is the only want to update a related record field through the UI or through an `@AuraEnabled` function on the server?

This is my attempt with two `force:recordData`'s in the compononent

```
<aura:attribute name="prescription" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="patient" type="Object" />

<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" />
<force:recordData aura:id="prescriptionHandler"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetError="{!v.prescriptionError}"
                  targetFields="{!v.prescription}"
                  mode="EDIT" />

<force:recordData aura:id="patientHandler"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetFields="{!v.patient}"
                  mode="EDIT" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't normally update related records in this manner; there's only one API that can do this, and Lightning doesn't have access to it.

The obvious solution is to have a second force:recordData component somewhere and set the fields you'd like to save, something like this:

```
var forceData = component.find("patientUpdate");
forceData.set("v.recordId", prescription.Patient__c);
forceData.set("v.targetFields", 
  { Id: prescription.Patient__c, 
    Authorize_Dot_Net_Profile_Id__c: parsed.customerProfileId });
forceData.saveRecord();
```

*Note*: I haven't actually tested this code, so it may require some adjustment.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working. I'm wondering if the component doesn't like two `force:recordData` in it. This code looks right though.

Comment: I've update my post with both `force:recordData`'s

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to achieve this using the implementation of LDS you have. LDS supports only primitive DML operations on the record retrieved by the record id specified. In this case, it’s basically an additional operation on a record which is not retrieved by the record id but is in a relationship to the record. Refer to this excerpt from [considerations for LDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm):

> Lightning Data Service supports primitive DML operations—create, read, update, and delete. It operates on one record at a time, which you retrieve or modify using the record ID

You may need to handle this using your own code as the same reference mentions.

> Lightning Data Service is powerful and simple to use. However, it’s not a complete replacement for writing your own data access code.